# AS3 Regex and the File.separator

Tags: regex, actionscript-3

I am on a Windows machine, and I am looking for a way to use Regex to count the number of occurrences of the File.separator characters in a path. Below is my code, and it outputs 0 every time.

```
    var dummyPath:String = "C:" + File.separator + "A" + File.separator + "B.jpg";
    var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(File.separator,"g");
    trace(dummyPath.match(pattern).length);
    //Outputs 0
```

I'm not sure what else to do.

Comment: For `match` you don't need the `g` flag just fyi.  Aside from that though, what does `trace(dummyPath)` output?

Comment: trace(dummyPath) gives me C:\A\B.jpg. I think I'm going with Panzercrisis' solution because it works..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use a regex in a case like this, just because they're a lot more confusing to work with (and I think a lot more inefficient as well) than usual string operations, and you aren't doing anything here that's complicated enough to make up for the difference.

In that case, I would just go about it this way:

```
var dummyPath:String = "C:" + File.separator + "A" + File.separator + "B.jpg";
trace(dummyPath.split(File.separator).length - 1);
```

As for what you're running into though, remember that operating systems' file separators are generally either `/` or `\`.  You're saying you're running this on Windows.  That means you're passing `"\"` into the constructor for the regex.  `\` is used to begin escape sequences in regexes the same way it's used like that in strings.

So essentially you're not describing a regex that looks for instances of `"\"` on a Windows machine; you're describing a regex that starts an escape sequence and doesn't finish.  So to use a regex in this case, you would need to escape `\` with another `\`:

```
// This is technically untested, but the principle is the same.
var pattern:RegExp = new RegExp(File.separator.replace("\\", "\\\\"), "g");
```

Answer (score 2):

Its not matching because the file separator you are using is a metacharacter.
The escape `\`.

The regex engine expects metachars, used as literals, to be escaped.

Try `\\`, which would be "\\\\" as a double quoted string.

If you run into a forward slash separator, just escape it too, does no harm.

So, concatenate the variable with an escape as a string Sep = "\\" + Sep; or something.